# Sliders working fine in desktop but not in mobile version why?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using UX builder theme.

Page link: [here]

In this page we used only sliders.. In mobile view slider's sections are overlapping except last slider (link).. tried everything but not getting solution.. Today I removed 2 sections from last slider (Blends of Natural Ingredients) then its coming proper in mobile version. But I need those sections.. What went wrong, where I did wrong, anyone pls..

The same issue having with blog posts.. [link]

Waiting for your valuable response..

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Looks like your sliders work fine if you resize the page, maybe something is not loaded when you initialize your slider ?

Comment: Some what removed overlapping from the sliders... but there is lot of space in the left hand side. I am not getting how to fix.. Not getting how to set values for slider transform:translateX ? If we set it correct then it will work fine.. Anyone pls let me know